# Android upload service upload image in a json array

Tags: android, json

I want to know if the android upload service can work like this, I need to put the image in a JSON array so that the string I'm sending is structured like this:

```
{"ArchivoItem":["ArchivoImg":"**>>IMAGE GOES HERE<<**", "ArchivoNombre":"cedula", "ArchivoExtension":"jpg"]}
```

and I'm wondering if the android upload service would work for this purpose, for example, I could try like this:

```
//Creating a multi part request
        new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                .addArrayParameter("ArchivoItem", 
                .addFileToUpload(path, "ArchivoImg"), //Adding file
                .addParameter("ArchivoNombre", "cedula"),
                .addParameter("ArchivoExtension", "jpg")   
                                   ) 
                .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                .setMaxRetries(2)
                .startUpload(); //Starting the upload
```

would this code create a string like the one above?

Comment: If the image is not too large, encode to base64 and add the base64 to your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

As said,in the comments, u can encode to base64 and add the base64 to your JSON.

```
public string ImageToBase64(Image image, 
  System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    // Convert Image to byte[]
    image.Save(ms, format);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    return base64String;
  }
}
```